# Regex removes swedish characters. it shouldnt

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have this formula for checking if a name is correct and removing non letters. however if my name have å, å or ö in the name it will remove that letter since its not a part of the english alphabet

```
<?php
//mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
function ValidName($namn = NULL, $efternamn = NULL){
if(isset($namn)) {
$namn = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '',  $namn);
return $namn;
}
if(isset($efternamn)) {
$efternamn = preg_replace('/\P{L}+/', '',  $efternamn);
return $efternamn;
}

}
?>
```

i tried adding the u after / to allow unicode letters, but then it just stole the entire name.
ive got this row in the file aswell: mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

so how would i keep the name correctly but lose dots, commas, numbers and everything you cant be named?

proper name: hellström

after my formula has been used: hellstrm

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you proceed, obligatory article [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). It's best to allow user to put anything for their names (unless it is some system where the real name of the user is compulsory, and the name is later matched with normalized database).

---

Back to the problem, there are two ways to represent `ö`, `ö` (U+00F6) as single code point or `ö` as two code points (`o` and combining diaeresis U+0308)

When you want to allow letter in any language, it is necessary to allow all characters in [Letter and Mark categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category):

```
$efternamn = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{M}]+/', '',  $efternamn);
```

This method is quite crude, since it doesn't check whether the combining marks are placed properly or not.

If the regex above doesn't work, try adding [`u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to the regex above.

Comment: i know about the name problem. but the system im building it for only accept swedish acceptable letters. so the c from french or u from germany wont be allowed. but your solution still gave me hellstrm even with the u modifier

Comment: hmmm, if i add the preg_replace in the main file it works. but if i place the preg_replace in the function file it doesnt work

Comment: the problem is that the function accepts multiple variables. then it strips the ö for some reason. marked your answer as the solution

Comment: @Henk: Have you tried using the mb_internal_encoding in the function file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use unicode property `\P{L}` to detect all unicode non letters:

```
$efternamn = preg_replace('/\P{L}+/', '',  $efternamn);
```

Comment: im still getting hellstrm from that. ill post the entire code in the main post

Comment: But you still have `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '',  $namn);` in your code.

Comment: but $namn and $efternamn is not the same. and ive applied it to $efternamn already. dont need to use it on $namn

Comment: Can you show output of `var_dump($efternamn);` before and after this `preg_replace` call?

Comment: string(9) "hellström" string(8) "hellstrm". string 9 is before. string 8 is after